# How to hide a broken ASP.NET Image Control

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, web

I've only been able to find how to hide broken images for an image added with  tag.

i.e.`<img src="sample.jpg" onerror="this.style.display='none';">`

How would I do this in .net with an image control?

Here's my code:

```
<asp:Image AlternateText='<%#Eval("DisplayName") %>'  ID="newsImage" width="77" height="57" align="middle" valign="top" runat="server"  Visible='<%# Eval("ImageName").ToString() != "" %>'  ImageUrl='<%#String.Format("../images/products/{0}", Eval("ImageName")) %>' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 possibilities. You can hide the `Image` or change the url to a `noimage.jpg` for example when the file is not found.

```
<asp:Image Visible='<%# System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(String.Format("../images/products/{0}", Eval("ImageName")))) %>' ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("../images/products/{0}", Eval("ImageName")) %>' runat="server" ID="Image1" />

<asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(String.Format("../images/products/{0}", Eval("ImageName")))) ? String.Format("../images/products/{0}", Eval("ImageName")) : "no-image.jpg" %>' runat="server" ID="Image2" />
```

Comment: I had to change the Server.MapPath to "~/images/products/{0}" because "../images/products/{0}" was throwing an error, but this worked. I opted to show a blank image in place of the broken image. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you just care about not displaying a broken image in client-browser, you can just use -

```
<asp:Image ... onerror="this.style.display='none';" />
```